# Numpy convert 10 base number to a bit flag in 10 sized array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have numpy array of numbers in range 0-9, and I would like to convert the numbers to a 'flag' in the index of said number. Following code does exactly what I would like:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a = np.array([5, 2, 7])

In [3]: b = np.zeros((3, 10))

In [4]: for i in range(a.shape[0]):
   ...:     b[i][a[i]] = 1
   ...:

In [5]: b
Out[5]:
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.]])
```

But I am wondering what is this conversion called, and is there a Numpy way to do this?

Comment: `b[np.arange(3), a] = 1`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `np.arange`:

```
b[np.arange(a.shape[0]), a] = 1
```